# Display Selected Regions in Homepage in Drupal 8

Tags: templates, drupal, twig, drupal-8, theming

My issue is this. I am creating a Drupal 8 theme, already declared regions and themed them in the page.html.twig. I created some regions just for the homepage, but now they appear also in content pages and so. My question is: How do you select regions to appear only in a specific page? Do I need to create twig files for each region? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a "page--front.html.twig" file on your theme, and add only the regions you need on this page as you did on the page.html.twig one.

Then delete the regions you don't need in the other pages from the page.html.twig.